# How to build/represent's worktree of git bare repo on memory with libgit2

Tags: git, rust, libgit2

I'm building a git server written in rust, I'm using git2 library that is a bindings of libgit2 for rust.

Actually i can create bare repository though the API, now i want build the worktree on memory from the bare repo for later serve and render the worktree in the web ui, but i do not understand how to make it.

Git2 provides Repository and Worktree structures for manipulate it, both haves methods for work with worktrees whether to create, operate, or open them, but both requires or exist in the repo (which would no longer be a bare repo), or for create worktrees make it in the repo(which would no longer be a bare repo).

I think that i'm speaking is about "the process for build verify copy (worktree) from git objects", but i dot not understand how this works, in the git pro book in the chapter 10 section 2 the book speaks about how git represents a worktree (the objects tree and blobs), but i do not find how "the process works".

can anyone share a resource on this, or explain me what I'm missing?

Comment: the actually code is https://gitlab.com/al3xio/immunity-server/-/tree/master/, in the repository model i don't have method to open from location, but i understand (or i think) that's the firs step for build/represents the worktree on memory

Comment: Creating a full working tree *in memory* is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. (Full trees may be hundreds of gigabytes in some of the larger projects out there.) Normally you'd create, at most, a tree-of-files in memory, and then if someone wants to see a file, or diff a particular pair of files, access the underlying blob objects in question, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comment of @torek, I just found a way to traverse the file tree, getting the **head** of the repo as a `Reference` struct, this struct provides the method `peel_to_tree()` that returns the underlying tree to the reference as a `Tree` structure and this provides the `walk` method, and from here i inspect the tree.

```rust
    let repo = Repository::open_bare( Path::new("/some/path.git") ).expect("error open repo");
    
    let head = repo.head().expect("error");

    let tree = head.peel_to_tree();

    match tree {
        Ok(tree) => {
            let mut ct = 0;
            tree.walk( TreeWalkMode::PreOrder, |root, entry| {
                println!("root_path: {}\nName: {}\nKind: {:?}\n\n", root, entry.name().expect("error name"), entry.kind().expect("error kind")  );
                ct +=1;
                TreeWalkResult::Ok
            } ).unwrap();

            println!("All entries: {}",ct);
        },
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure how good or bad this process is, but I think it's a good starting point for what I want to do.